# How to process the cube by using xmla in c# coding

Tags: c#, ssas, xmla

I have list of analysis services databases, and their cubes and dimensions.
Now i want to process the selected cube in c# by using linq to xml? how to give the  instruction to process.
Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

check this out for sending XMLA commands...
http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2006/05/25/xmlaClient.aspx

and this link should give you an idea of actual XMLA commands that need to be sent...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187199(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Polvo... I asked question to process using XMLA not with adomdclient. there is difference between those two terms.. can you please correct your answer...?

Comment: sorry about that Mihir...if you edit your original question, I can remove the down vote...